# How would one tell if the following ODE has any singular solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

The ODE is $y'(x) + \frac{y(x)}{x}=-x^4y(x)^3$.

I found the solution to be:

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}x^3+C}}$$

but I'm not sure what is meant by "singular" solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: See more examples of singular solutions here http://server.math.umanitoba.ca/courses/math2800/Singular.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is a solution to the differential equation that isn't actually included in the solution you found above if such a solution exists. For example, your solution says y cannot be 0. But y can be 0. Since 0+0=0

The singular solution is $y=0$

Comment: Do you want me to copy my above comment here? and delete my comment? Like I thought he was asking to find the singular solution so that is what I stated.

Comment: There, I edit the answer to include my comment which gave the reason why I said it was the singular solution. Just thought it was pointless to repeat myself.

Comment: I guess I will just delete the comment now.